# Python -Cannot remove list item

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I have to remove a particular given element. I used `list1=[0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]` and `remove_element=2`

```py
def fun(list1,remove_element):
   if len(list1)==0:
       return 0
   for i in range(len(list1)):
       if remove_element==list1[i]:
           list1.remove(remove_element)
   return list1
```

here is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#205>", line 1, in <module>
   print(fun(list1,remove_element))
   File "<pyshell#204>", line 5, in fun
        if remove_element==list1[i]:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `return [x for x in list1 if x != remove_element]`

Comment: Your problem is that once you remove the element from the list, it has grown shorter by one element, so the range you're iterating over becomes longer than the list once you've removed the item

Answer (score 1):

Another shorter solution would be

```
def fun(list1,remove_element):
    while remove_element in list1:
        list1.remove(remove_element)
    return list1
```

Comment: Hii thanks for the nice response. but if you could point the error in my code and rectify it that would be great learning for me. thanks

Comment: The problem with your code is that your loop depend on the pre-computed len(list), but you're removing element in list, so the actual len is different when looping. Also the remove method automaticaly remove the first element match so you dont need to loop over the list.

Comment: This works of course, but it might be worth noting that the complexity is quadratic (because of the `in` being in a list, not a set), making it very unoptimized. Returning a new list would be faster but would also take up more space. A generator function could probably work better

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def fun(list1,remove_element):
    if len(list1)==0:
        return 0
    newlist = list(filter((remove_element).__ne__, list1))
    print(newlist)
    return newlist
```

Running

```
fun(['1', '2', '3'], '1')

get [2,3]
```

Comment: hii , thanks for the response but it is not working for the  list1=[0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2],remove_element=2. it give output [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2], but i am expecting output=[0, 1, 3, 0, 4]

Comment: @viveksingh Try  `newlist = list(filter((remove_element).__ne__, list1))`